# Determine if array element represents an object or a value

Tags: javascript

From a JSON object (containing stock data), I want to add certain elements to an array (in Google Sheets script editor):

```
var quote = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

// Example of what quote object looks like:

{
    "quoteSummary": {
        "result": [
            {
                "Profile": {
                    "sector": "Technology",
                    "website": "www.test.com"
                },
                "Owners": [
                    {
                        "name": "Eric",
                        "age": "28"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Susan",
                        "age": "44"
                    }
                ],
                "Profit": 100,
                "Assets": 7000
            }
        ]   
    }
}
```

Here is my current approach to read only some specific values:

```
var arr   = [];

arr.push(quote.quoteSummary.result[0].Profile.sector); // Technology
arr.push(quote.quoteSummary.result[0].Owners[1].name); // Susan
arr.push(quote.quoteSummary.result[0].Profit);         // 100
```

But since there are many specific properties to read, I'd like to use a loop:

```
var quote = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
var arr   = [];

var el = [
    ['Profile', 'sector'],
    ['Owners[1]', 'name'],
    ['Profit']
];

for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++)
{
    if (quote.quoteSummary.result[0][el[i][0]][el[i][1]] !== undefined)
    {
        arr.push(quote.quoteSummary.result[0][el[i][0]][el[i][1]].value);
    }
}

/*
Expected output (if I would loop through arr):
Technology
Susan
100
*/
```

The point is that different stocks, will have different properties. So `el` might define some non-existing elements or properties. Assume (in a bit of an other way of defining `el` -- as I wrote, I'm plexible here.. perhaps the paths are the easiest):

```
var el = [
    'Profile.website',
    'Profile.name',
    'Assets'
]

/*
Expected output:

www.test.com
                 <----- "name" doesn't exist!
7000

Notice that in this example, there is no property "name" in Profile,
so I'd like to add an empty element to arr
*/
```

But this does not work. What is a generic loop that accomplishes what I'm trying to do here? The array defining what I want can also be constructed differently if that helps. But the point is that I don't end up with a script like:

```
arr.push(quote.quoteSummary.result[0].Profile.something);
arr.push(quote.quoteSummary.result[0].Profile.something);
arr.push(quote.quoteSummary.result[0].Profile.something);
arr.push(quote.quoteSummary.result[0].Profile.something);
arr.push(quote.quoteSummary.result[0].Profile.something);
arr.push(quote.quoteSummary.result[0].Profile.something);
arr.push(quote.quoteSummary.result[0].Profile.something);
arr.push(quote.quoteSummary.result[0].Profile.something);
arr.push(quote.quoteSummary.result[0].Profile.something);
arr.push(quote.quoteSummary.result[0].Profile.something);
arr.push(quote.quoteSummary.result[0].Profile.something);
```

Comment: It's unclear to me exactly what the goal is. Do you have examples of the input and output data? Would this work for your purposes? ``var value = typeof y === 'object' && y.hasOwnProperty(value) ? y.value : y``

Comment: The goal is indeed to check if `y1 y2 y3` have a property called `value` or if `y1 y2 y3` is the value itself, apologies if I'm not explaining well. Translated into my situation, your solution would read: `if (fmt = typeof quote.quoteSummary.result[0][el[i][0]][el[i][1]] && quote.quoteSummary.result[0][el[i][0]].hasOwnProperty("value")) { arr.push(quote.quoteSummary.result[0][el[i][0]][el[i][1]].value); }` but this throws an error "Reference not defined"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you use variable-length chains of property names. Each name in a given chain represents a deeper property. You can "dive" into an object through an arbitrary number of property names with code like this:

```
let dive = (obj, propertyNames) => {
  for (let pn of propertyNames) obj = obj[pn];
  return obj;
};
```

Now you can say:

```js
let dive = (obj, propertyNames) => {
  for (let pn of propertyNames) obj = obj[pn];
  return obj;
};

let quote = {
  quoteSummary: {
    result: [
      {
        Profile: {
          sector: 'Technology',
          website: 'www.test.com'
        },
        Owners: [
          {
            name: 'Eric',
            age: '28'
          },
          {
            name: 'Susan',
            age: '44'
          }
        ],
        Profit: 100,
        Assets: 7000
      }
    ]
  }
};

// Here are the "variable-length property chains":
let el = [
  [ 'Profile', 'sector' ],
  [ 'Owners', 1, 'name' ],
  [ 'Profit' ]
];

// Here's how to combine `el`, `dive`, and your `quote` data to get a result:
let arr = el.map(propertyNames => dive(quote.quoteSummary.result[0], propertyNames));

console.log(arr);
```

You could even replace `dive` with `Array.prototype.reduce`, if you'd like to stay functional but avoid the function definition:

```
dive(someObj, propertyNames);
```

is equivalent to

```
propertyNames.reduce((obj, propName) => obj[propName], someObj);
```

Note the above code all assumes that a property exists for each term in the property chain (except the final property name, which may resolve to `undefined` without causing any errors). If some cases may have the, e.g., `Profile` key `undefined` or `null` you'll need to write some kind of `if (propertyDoesntExist)` / `else` statement which describes how to deal with missing properties.

For example you could modify `dive` to handle non-existent properties:

```
let dive = (obj, propertyNames, valueIfMissing=null) => {
  for (let pn of propertyNames) {
    // Intentional use of loose `==` operator!
    if (obj == null) return valueIfMissing;
    obj = obj[pn];
  }
  return obj;
};
```

This means that:

```
dive({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, [ 'd' ]) === null;
```

But we can substitute any default return value:

```
dive({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, [ 'd' ], 'ddd') === 'ddd';
```

Note this works at any depth:

```
dive({ a: { a: 1 }, b: { b: 2 }, c: { c: 3 }, d: null }, [ 'd', 'd' ]) === null;
dive({ a: { a: 1 }, b: { b: 2 }, c: { c: 3 }, d: null }, [ 'd', 'd' ], 'ddd') === 'ddd';
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this:

```
if(y.value){
  arr.push(y.value);
} else {
  arr.push(y);
}
```

However, this will break if y.value happens to be something like 0, false, etc.
If this is the case you can do this:

```
if(y.hasOwnProperty("value")){
  arr.push(y.value);
} else {
  arr.push(y);
}
```

Based on the comment:

```
if (quote.quoteSummary.result[0][el[i][0]].hasOwnProperty("value")) { 
    arr.push(quote.quoteSummary.result[0][el[i][0]].value);
} else {
    arr.push(quote.quoteSummary.result[0][el[i][0]]);
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying. I tried `if (quote.quoteSummary.result[0][el[i][0]].hasOwnProperty("value")) { arr.push(quote.quoteSummary.result[0][el[i][0]][el[i][1]].value);}` but then I get an error "Reference does not exist"?

Comment: I think it should be this: `if (quote.quoteSummary.result[0][el[i][0]].hasOwnProperty("value")) { 
    arr.push(quote.quoteSummary.result[0][el[i][0]].value);
} else {
    arr.push(quote.quoteSummary.result[0][el[i][0]]);
}`